# Java Program To Solve The Quadratic Equation Does Not Work

Tags: java

I am using classes to try to do this task, I feel like the computer thinks I made the numbers out of order, and they do not solve in the correct sequence.

The Quadratic Runner

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    
        import static java.lang.System.*;
    
        public class QuadraticRunner
    
        {
            public static void main( String[] args )
            {
                Scanner keyboard = new Scanner( System.in );
                out.print("Enter a :: ");
                int quadA = keyboard.nextInt();
                out.print("Enter b :: ");
                int quadB = keyboard.nextInt();
                out.print("Enter c :: ");
                int quadC = keyboard.nextInt();
                
                
                Quadratic test = new Quadratic();
                System.out.println( test.getRootOne( quadA,quadB,quadC ) );
                System.out.println( test.getRootTwo( quadA,quadB,quadC ) );
            }
        }
```

The Quadratic

```
public class Quadratic
{
    public static double getRootOne( int a, int b, int c )
    {
        double Quad = (b*b)-(4*a*c);
        double sqrt = Math.sqrt(Quad);
        Quad = ((double)Quad + b);
        Quad = ((double)Quad/(2*a));
        return Quad;

    
        
          
} 
    public static double getRootTwo( int a, int b, int c )
    {
    double Quad = (b*b)-(4*a*c);
    double sqrt = Math.sqrt(Quad);
    Quad = ((double)Quad - b);
    Quad = ((double)Quad/(2*a));
    return Quad;
        
    
    }
}
```

When I try to plug the numbers into the program the numbers being 1, 1, 1 it comes out as
Root 1 = -1.0
Root 2 = -2.0

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code?

Comment: Java naming conventions have variables and methods starting with a lower case letter (quad). Also, you tend to use casting when it isn't necessary, casting a double to a double.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 minor mistakes in your code:

1. You never use the `sqrt` variable you define in the second line of your methods (should be used in line 3 of the methods)
2. You have switched up the order of arguments in the 3rd line of your methods (the quadratic formula is `b +/- sqrt(...)` and not `sqrt(...) +/- b`)

I suppose this should give you the correct answers:

```java
public class Quadratic {
    public static double getRootOne(int a, int b, int c) {
        double quad = (b*b)-(4*a*c);
        double sqrt = Math.sqrt(quad);
        quad = (b + (double) sqrt); //original: ((double)quad + b);
        quad = ((double)quad/(2*a));
        return quad;          
    } 

    public static double getRootTwo(int a, int b, int c) {
        double quad = (b*b)-(4*a*c);
        double sqrt = Math.sqrt(quad);
        quad = (b - (double) sqrt); //original: ((double)quad - b);
        quad = ((double)quad/(2*a));
        return quad;   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
    
        import static java.lang.System.*;
    
        public class QuadraticRunner
    
        {
            public static void main( String[] args )
            {
                Scanner keyboard = new Scanner( System.in );
                out.print("Enter a :: ");
                int quadA = keyboard.nextInt();
                out.print("Enter b :: ");
                int quadB = keyboard.nextInt();
                out.print("Enter c :: ");
                int quadC = keyboard.nextInt();
                
                System.out.println( Quadratic.getRootOne( quadA,quadB,quadC ) );
                System.out.println( Quadratic.getRootTwo( quadA,quadB,quadC ) );
            }
        

public class Quadratic
{
    public static   double getRootOne( int a, int b, int c )
    {
        double Quad = (b*b)-(4*a*c);
        double sqrt = Math.sqrt(Quad);
        Quad = ((double)Quad + b);
        Quad = ((double)Quad/(2*a));
        return Quad;          
} 
    public static double getRootTwo( int a, int b, int c )
    {
    double Quad = (b*b)-(4*a*c);
    double sqrt = Math.sqrt(Quad);
    Quad = ((double)Quad - b);
    Quad = ((double)Quad/(2*a));
    return Quad;
        
   
    }
}
}
```

In the above code, you should use the class name not the object as you created a test to call the static method to the public static void main method